# Is getting the page name of the powerbi report when published in the web by design?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

[image]

I disabled the option in the report settings too.

[image]

Please let me know if it is a part of design or can be removed easily.

Answer (score 2):

The `report` pages `navigation` tabs can easily be hidden by setting `navContentPaneEnabled` of `settings` property as `false` in the embed configuration object.

Please refer below code snippet for `embed configuration object:`

```js
const embedConfig = {
        type: "report",
        tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,
        accessToken: "ACCESS TOKEN",
        embedUrl: "EMBED URL",
        settings: {
            navContentPaneEnabled: false
        }
 };
```

Please refer docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/configure-report-settings#page-navigation